# Unable to open the generated docx4j document other than MS-Word Application

Tags: java, docx4j

Below is Code for generating the Document using docx4j. I am able to open the generated document only in MS-Word Application.

When I mail the generated document, receiver is unable to view the document.

```
 private static void documentGenerator(String html, File file) throws Docx4JException, JAXBException {
//Word Processing Package
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = getWordMLPackage();
NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();
AlternativeFormatInputPart inputPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(AltChunkType.Xhtml);
inputPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));
inputPart.setBinaryData(html.getBytes());
Relationship altChunkRel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(inputPart);
// .. the bit in document body
CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId());
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(ac);
// .. content type
wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager().addDefaultContentType("html", "text/html");
//Saving the Document
wordMLPackage.save(file);
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens and which application is used to open the file at the receiver ?

Comment: What application is the receiver using?  Sounds like it can't handle AlternativeFormatInputPart(AltChunkType.Xhtml).  You have more control using XhtmlImporter; it won't happen if you use that.

Comment: @JasonPlutext I tried with XhtmlImporter too. Same issue Exist

Comment: @Marged receiver is trying to open the document in google docs. It shows a blank document when the document is download receiver is also able to see doc in MS-Word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used XhtmlImporter to generate the document,then the compatibility problem is resolved.

Below is Code Snippet

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(ndp);
ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering();
AlternativeFormatInputPart inputPart = new AlternativeFormatInputPart(AltChunkType.Xhtml);
inputPart.setContentType(new ContentType("text/html"));
inputPart.setBinaryData(html.getBytes());
Relationship altChunkRel = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(inputPart);
// .. the bit in document body
CTAltChunk ac = Context.getWmlObjectFactory().createCTAltChunk();
ac.setId(altChunkRel.getId());
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(ac);
// .. content type
wordMLPackage.getContentTypeManager().addDefaultContentType("html", "text/html");
//Saving the Document
wordMLPackage.save(file);
```